# How to crop a part of a image

Tags: c#, minecraft

In c# how can I crop a part of a picture like they do in minecraft

[image: example]

thanks in advance

Comment: Need more details - otherwise: open in Paint and cut/paste...

Comment: Was the image really necessary? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the `Graphics.DrawImage` overloads that allows you to select just part of the source, for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040.aspx

> Draws the **specified portion of the specified Image** at the specified location and with the specified size.